# Sharepoint 2007 Publishing sites and integrating the blog site template

Tags: blog, publishing-site, 2007

Has anyone had any experience of using the MOSS blog template for publishing sites?

It seems you have to turn off the ‘ViewFormPagesLockDown’ feature to stop authentication prompts when clicking the blog title. It also seems that you can’t apply your custom master page and are stuck with the application page style.

If anyone has managed to customize it or do anything at all please share!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I attempted to use the Out of the Box Blog template on my personal website and encountered similar problems. I settled on Wordpress first until I found a host that could support the Community Kit for SharePoint Enhanced Blog Edition. Have you tried it?
I know that many others have succesfully gotten blogs working on anonymous, public sites before including [SharePoint Evolved](http://www.sharepointevolved.com/blog/default.aspx). You might try sending Isaac, @MrIsaac on Twitter, a query about the process he went through.